# SQL Server: show default value for NULL in Select

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, null, default-value

I have a stored procedure that creates an XML string based on some selects.

Is there a way I can show a default if one of the selects returns NULL ?
Basically I just want to keep the same structure in my XML independent of whether a value is NULL or not (currently the XML only shows records with a value).

**Example stored procedure:**

```
SELECT      A.ranking,
            (
                SELECT      B.groupName,
                            (
                                SELECT      C.policy,
                                            C.groupCount
                                FROM        @temp C
                                WHERE       C.ranking = A.ranking
                                AND         C.groupName = B.groupName
                                ORDER BY    C.groupCount desc, C.policy
                                FOR XML PATH(''), ELEMENTS, TYPE
                            ) AS groupName
                FROM        @temp B
                WHERE       B.ranking = A.ranking
                GROUP BY    B.groupName
                ORDER BY    B.groupName
                FOR XML PATH(''), ELEMENTS, TYPE
            )
FROM        @temp A
GROUP BY    A.ranking
ORDER BY    A.ranking
FOR XML PATH('policyRanking'), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT('ranks')
```

Many thanks for any help with this, Tim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
SELECT      coalesce(A.ranking,0) as ranking
            (
                SELECT      coalesce(B.groupName,'') as groupName,
                            (
                                SELECT      C.policy,
                                            C.groupCount
                                FROM        @temp C
                                WHERE       C.ranking = A.ranking
                                AND         C.groupName = B.groupName
                                ORDER BY    C.groupCount desc, C.policy
                                FOR XML PATH(''), ELEMENTS, TYPE
                            ) AS groupName
                FROM        @temp B
                WHERE       B.ranking = A.ranking
                GROUP BY    B.groupName
                ORDER BY    B.groupName
                FOR XML PATH(''), ELEMENTS, TYPE
            )
FROM        @temp A
GROUP BY    A.ranking
ORDER BY    A.ranking
FOR XML PATH('policyRanking'), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT('ranks')
```

Comment: Thanks ! Can you explain what coalesce does here ?

Comment: COALESCE sets the value entered as second parameter if the column in NULL

Answer (score 3):

Use [ISNULL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) function, by replacing each NULLable column (see table definition) with the expression:

```
 ISNULL ( column , default_value )
```